# No USB devices detected in Android Studio 6.0.1

Tags: android-studio, debugging, usb

I used to run applications in my **Redmi** **3s** **Prime** device. Usually it worked, but now it's showing as no USB devices detected.

Developer options and USB debugging is ON, but it is still not detecting. What should I do?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen can you help me .

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Android Studio "event log" information.

If the information is like "**ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon ***", it means that other software holds the port. [Referring to this](http://blog.csdn.net/xiaanming/article/details/9401981) can solve it.

If you cannot find log information, probably it failed to install the driver.
You may disconnect the phone from your computer, restart the mobile phone and try again.

Comment: cannot find log info. When I tried to run via terminal first i try to list the devices.Then it didn't list my device. So i tried to run via the 'Run' button, then it displays no devices detected

Comment: I'm using ubuntu os. So the above is step is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Redmi 3S and that happened to me too. I solved it by installing the [correct drivers](http://xiaomiadvices.com/download-xiaomi-usb-drivers/) from here and [MI PC Suite](http://pcsuite.mi.com/) and connected the device.

Also in developer options, **turn on** "Install via USB", "USB debugging" and **turn off** "Verify apps over USB". If nothing works, try another USB cable or other port.

Comment: but i used to run applications in my Redmi 3s prime. At that time there were no problems!

Comment: Android Studio just does this stuff :p try install MI PC Suite as i said and check if you can connect your device.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu os!

Answer (score 0):

Restart PC, Restart phone, if no luck,
Try installing usb driver from this link
http://gsmusbdriver.com/xiaomi-redmi-3s
and try again

Answer (score 0):

Download suitable USB Driver, ADB driver and fastboot driver for Xiaomi Redmi 3s Prime from below link and install them on your computer.

https://www.androidusbdrivers.com/xiaomi-redmi-3s-prime-usb-drivers/

After installing restart your computer.